# firebase cloud functions deploy throwing node error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm following a cloud functions tutorial and I'm trying to deploy cloud functions using firebase deploy -- functions only, and it worked the first time, but I realized I forgot to save the index.js file so no functions were deployed. When I saved and tried again it threw me a node error:  [image]

My functions look like this:
[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the code into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue with your code but rather with the `winston` package the firebase CLI is using, and is probably related to: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1573

Comment: They saw a similar message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734530/7674214). Following their instructions, please try run "npm cache clean" and reinstall firebase tools. Then, try again to deploy and share with us your results.