# Firebase Can't Deploy

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a firebase project I've been maintaining for months and haven't had any problems with.

I've tried running `firebase deploy` multiple times to no avail. I've googled it and searched on SO, github, and others, [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475477/an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-after-firebase-deploy) [these](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/756) [links](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/756), none of which worked. I've tried updating firebase tools, uninstalling and reinstalling, and everything between. Please don't blindly flag as duplicate without reading.

The first line of my error looks like this:

```
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:307
  throw ex;
```

Here's my full output:

```
firebase deploy
```

C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:307
throw ex;
^

Error: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:261:12)
at PassThrough.Writable.write (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:305:21)
at File.log (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\transports\file.js:185:34)
at File._write (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston-transport\index.js:103:17)
at doWrite (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:428:64)
at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:417:5)
at File.Writable.write (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:334:11)
at DerivedLogger.ondata (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:681:20)
at DerivedLogger.emit (events.js:203:15)
at DerivedLogger.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at addChunk (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:298:12)
at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:280:11)
at DerivedLogger.Readable.push (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:241:10)
at DerivedLogger.Transform.push (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:139:32)
at DerivedLogger._transform (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:305:12)
at DerivedLogger.Transform._read (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:177:10)

I'm completely stuck on this, I've been searching for an hour, and I've never had this fail for me before, so I don't know what's going on with firebase. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others that come this way, I had this exact error message and stack trace. I was attempting to run `firebase deploy --except functions` while following this [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/?authuser=0#12) step.

For me the fix was simply to stop serving the firebase app locally for debug.

Once I had done this, no reboot, just back in the other terminal and submit the deploy command and it worked fine.

The code lab gets you to do this and then leave it served locally while changing various parts of the app, but I have no idea what caused winston to conflict this way.

Comment: Stopping the local firebase app just fixed it for me, again having this issue in Nov 2020. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

This probably an issue with NPM try running `npm cache clean` and reinstall firebase tools. If that didn't work try contacting [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support). Recently I ran into an issue with firebase hosting and they were really helpful but took about 30 hours for their response after making the support ticket.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I was actually able to resolve it by trying a sixth time after restarting my computer a third time... I don't know why it just magically worked. I had internet the entire time and have firebase tools up to date, and I was able to run deploy just minutes before I was then unable to, but it works now for me so I guess my problem is solved.

Comment: Probably the issue was with cache. When you keep on restarting it might have gotten cleaned. Glad it your issue is fixed :)

Comment: Had the exact same problem and doing this worked for me. @Justin you should flag this as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) @D G

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error, I tried restarting `Command Prompt`, deleting the cache file in the `.firebase` project folder. `deploy` worked fine with a separate test project.

On a whim I shut down my local server, and `firebase deploy` worked fine. Not sure if that's the real fix, as I'm 99.9% sure I did deploys in the past with the local server running... but it works for me now.

And after deploy was working again, it stopped a second time with the same error. So I stopped the server, and once again `deploy` worked. Then if failed a third time, same fix, shut down the local server.

Local server was run via `firebase serve --only hosting`

`npm cache verify` also checked out A-OK:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html